# EvaluateAllFormulaCells in Slow in XSLX v/s XLS : POI 3.17

Tags: apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I am using Apache POI 3.17 and I have an Excel file which needs calculation. Lets assume that the whole excel file needs calculating!
When I save this file as `XLS` and then use the POI API's then the EvaluateAllFormulaCells is done in 1.5 seconds!
However the same file as XLSX, the EvaluateAllFormulaCells take 8.5 Seconds, sometimes even more.
For your information I have rounded out the possibility of corrupt file while changing the file types!
Any idea on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If you really wants a valuable answer, you should providing an example Excel file together with code which shows this behavior. In general, the evaluation of `*.xlsx` may differ in time consuming because of the maximum count of cells in a `*.xlsx` sheet is singly higher than in a `*.xls` sheet. But it should not differ as much for exactly the same sheet contents.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable response. The code is a single liner. EvaluateAllFormulaCells method call on same file saved as XLS is faster compared to the XLSX

Comment: "EvaluateAllFormulaCells method call on same file saved as XLS is faster compared to the XLSX": Well it is your assertion that this is true in all cases. I claim it is not true in all cases. So what now? As said, we need an example Excel file together with code which shows this behavior.

Comment: Ok good point :) i wish it is my impression on the topic. I am trying to figure out how I can give this excel file as it has few client specific data.
Let me come back.